# Why does this spring config file not resolve the mvc:resources element

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I cant get past this error. The mvc xsd is correct and validated that the resources element exists.  Why does this spring config file not resolve the mvc:resources element

**SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'**

I am using springframework v3.0.2

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan annotation-config="true" base-package="com.auto"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mvc:resources was introduced in 3.0.4 and you are using 3.0.2.  See the accepted answer to this question [Spring serving static content with mvc:resources, invalid xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829369/spring-serving-static-content-with-mvcresources-invalid-xsd)

Comment: Sure. I was keenly aware of that issue because it bit me several months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar containig the `spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` is deployed.  (When I remember right, it is `spring-mvc.jar`)