# serve static resource using spring 3.0.0 and tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, tomcat6, spring-webflow

I need to expose some static content (xsd files that are required by the wsdl). I cannot use the mvn:resources since it is not available in Spring 3.0.0

I don't have an idea as to where the static content should go. Hope someone can help me.

In my web.xml i have

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

then in the webapp dir I added a resources dir with the static files.

```
% ls webapp 
index.jsp  META-INF  resources  WEB-INF
```

can someone tell me where the static content should go.

thanks much.

Comment: Based on the following threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829369/spring-serving-static-content-with-mvcresources-invalid-xsd and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085964/why-does-this-spring-config-file-not-resolve-the-mvcresources-element that doesn't seem to be the case. I get the following error. How do I resolve in 3.0.0. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget this one aswell:

```
<!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource 
requests to the container's default Servlet -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> I cannot use the mvn:resources since it is not available in Spring 3.0.0

<strike>This is complete wrong!</strike>

`mvn:resources` is avaiable in Spring mvc namespace for version <strike>3.0.0</strike> 3.0.4

See the xsd: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

Comment: Based on the following threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829369/spring-serving-static-content-with-mvcresources-invalid-xsd and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085964/why-does-this-spring-config-file-not-resolve-the-mvcresources-element that doesn't seem to be the case. I get the following error. How do I resolve in 3.0.0. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'. Thanks much for replying.

Comment: Seams you are right, I did not noticed that is was introduced in a minor update.